# Find the distance between two points

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm learning on my own and having some problems understanding these 2 exercises:

1)
  $$ d = \sqrt{(-\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{3})^2+(0-(-\sqrt{5}))^2} $$
  $$  = \sqrt{6+2\sqrt{18}+3+5} = \sqrt{14+2\sqrt{9*2}} $$
  $$  = \sqrt{14+2*3\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{14+ 6\sqrt{2}}}  \approx 4.742 $$
2)
$$ \sqrt{(-\sqrt{2}-0)^2+(1-\sqrt{7})^2} = \sqrt{ 2 + 1 - 2\sqrt{7}+7}$$
$$ =\sqrt{10-2\sqrt{7}} \approx 2.170 $$

I don't understand in the first exercise where $ 2\sqrt{18} $ came from and in the other exercise $-2\sqrt{7}$

I would appreciate some help, thanks in advance

Comment: $(a\pm b)^2=a^2\pm 2ab+b^2$, I suppose

Comment: thanks, now it makes sense :)